# Sprichwort "einen Elch suchen"

Tags: idiom

Ein deutscher Freund von mir hat in einer E-Mail geschrieben:

> "du mußt nicht einen Elch suchen"

Damit hat er gemeint, dass ich nicht in Ewigkeit und vielleicht vergebens nach etwas suchen musste.

Ich hatte den Ausdruck früher nicht gehört, und fragte ihn deswegen nach dessen Bedeutung. Er war aber über die Herkunft dieses Ausdrucks nicht sicher, und wenn er seine (deutsche) Freunde nachfragte, waren nur wenige davon damit bekannt.

Weiß jemand etwas über die Verbreitung (örtlich und zeitlich) von der Redensart, und woher konnte sie kommen?

Comment: Das habe ich hier in Süddeutschland auch noch nie gehört.

Comment: Als ich den Elch suchte, knutsche mich ein Wolf. — Also die Redensarten lauten: "Ich glaub, mich knutsch ein Elch." und "Ich hab' mir nen Wolf gesucht." Hier scheint wohl jemandem der Elch durchgegangen zu sein. Ähm... Pferd, natürlich.

Comment: Ich kenne eher den Ausdruck "sich einen Wolf suchen". "Elch" ist mir noch nie in dem Zusamenhang untergekommen. Ich bin in Norddeutschland aufgewachsen und lebe nun im Süden.

Comment: Diesen Ausdruck habe ich noch nie gehört.

Comment: Niemand scheint dieses Sprichwort zu kennen, ist es möglich das dein Freund  das Sprichwort falsch wiedergegeben hat?

Comment: Es scheint als ob es hier um eine Kontamination handelt. Mein Freund ist im B-W geboren und aufgewachsen, scheint aber die Sache falsch verstanden zu haben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Den Ausdruck *du musst dir einen Elch suchen* gibt es nicht (wie immer ist aber Nicht-Existenz unmöglich zu belegen).

Man kann sich einen "*Wolf suchen*", was heisst, dass man so lange sucht, bis man einen "Wolf" hat. Mit dem [Wolf](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intertrigo) ist allerdings kein echter gemeint, sondern ein Ekzem oder eine Hautreizung, die auch als "Wolf" bezeichnet wird. Ich kenne den Ausdruck vom Militär, dort bekommt man nach langen Märschen hin und wieder "Wölfe" vom dauernden Reiben von Kleidung oder Ausrüstungsgegenständen auf der Haut - Man hat sich einen Wolf gelaufen.

Comment: Wir das Sprichwort oft so verwendet? "Sich einen Wolf" suchen habe ich noch nie gehört und wäre auch nicht auf den Zusammenhang mit "sich einen Wolf laufen" gekommen.

Comment: @Anetair "oft" ist relativ. Sagen wir mal so: Es ist nicht ungeläufig, aber auch nichts, was man wöchentlich hören würde.

Comment: Zumindest ist die Verwendung in übertragener Bedeutung „sich einen Wolf reden“ neben der Verwendung in der ursprünglichen Bedeutung „sich einen Wolf laufen“ häufig genug, um im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wolf_Raubtier_Maschine_Wundsein#Bedeutung3) aufgeführt zu werden.

Comment: "Sich einen Wolf" laufen wird selten verwendet, weil die meisten Leute selten einen 50km Marsch machen.